# SQL Server 2008 - Selecting multiple rows from OPENXML statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have an XML file and I open that in SQL Server using OPENXML and then read the values in the XML file and insert them into the table. Assume that the XML structure is like this

```
<Student>
   <name>XYZ</name>
   <id>123</id>
   <fathersname>XYS</fathersname>
   <fathersid>3489</fathersid>
</Student>".
```

Now I need to add this as two different rows and the DB should look like this

`Name`    `ID`
  `XYZ  123`
`XYS   3489`
 How can i read from this`XML` and insert as two different rows using a single `OPENXML` statement?

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Person(ID int, [Name] varchar(50))

DECLARE @docHandle int

DECLARE @xmlDocument XML
SET @xmlDocument = N'<ROOT>
<Student>
  <name>XYZ</name>
  <id>123</id>
  <fathersname>XYS</fathersname>
  <fathersid>3489</fathersid>
</Student>
<Student>
  <name>ABC</name>
  <id>456</id>
  <fathersname>DEF</fathersname>
  <fathersid>7859</fathersid>
</Student>
</ROOT>'

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @docHandle OUTPUT, @xmlDocument

-- student's data first
INSERT INTO dbo.Person
SELECT * 
  FROM OPENXML(@docHandle, N'/ROOT/Student',2) 
    WITH (id int, name varchar(50))

-- now insert father's data
INSERT INTO dbo.Person
SELECT * 
  FROM OPENXML(@docHandle, N'/ROOT/Student',2) 
    WITH (fathersid int, fathersname varchar(50))


SELECT * FROM dbo.Person

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @docHandle 
DROP TABLE dbo.Person
```

To open from a file:

```
declare @xmlDocument XML
SET @xmlDocument=(SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(
   BULK 'c:\Temp\Student.xml',
   SINGLE_BLOB) AS x)
```

**UPDATE:**
Sorry, did not see that you are trying to split `<father>` into a different row, I have simply added one more INSERT for that. If you need more control over the loading process, you can always consider setting up an ETL job in SSIS.

**UPDATE 2**
Well here is a creative way with one insert only, but two selects -- not sure about the performance at all. Again, we are splitting one record into two rows.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Person
    SELECT 
        x.e.value('id[1]', 'int') AS "id"
        ,x.e.value('name[1]', 'varchar(10)') AS "Name"  
    FROM @xmlDocument.nodes('/ROOT/Student') AS x(e)
    UNION
    SELECT 
        x.e.value('fathersid[1]', 'int') AS "id"
        ,x.e.value('fathersname[1]', 'varchar(10)') AS "Name"
    FROM @xmlDocument.nodes('/ROOT/Student') AS x(e);
```

Comment: Hi.. Is it possible to do this with only one insert and select statement? I was actually looking for that only..

Comment: Don't see how -- you are trying to split one record into two rows in one insert. But then there may be a creative way somehow...

Comment: Just for run look at UPDATE 2.